# Function to uncheck a checkbox related to a div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

I have this list of people with checkboxes next to their names. When you click on a checkbox, that person's name is added to a list of empty slots at the bottom of the page.

The list of empty slots are just empty divs with borders. And the default number is six. But I've made these two simple functions to add and remove the slots if the users needs to. They look like this:

```
function addSlot() {
    var count = jQuery('.member').length;
    var div_id = count + 1;
    $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + div_id + "' class='member'></div>");
}

function removeSlot() {
    var div_id = jQuery('.member').length;
    $('#member' + div_id + '').remove();
}
```

So yeah, they're pretty basic. Now the tricky thing I can't do, is make it so that if you remove a slot with a name in it, the corresponding checkbox becomes unchecked. Not sure how doable that is. Here's what my 'persons' and 'slots' look like:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='159' value='159' /><label for='159'>John Smith</label>
```

and

```
<div id="member1" class="member"></div>
```

So I guess I just need it so that if I remove a div that is populated, it takes the content of that div and uses it to uncheck the checkbox who's label corresponds to that content? That make sense?

Comment: Can you share some more of your js code that you have already, or set up a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net so we can play with your code.

Comment: @j08691, Opps, I typed that subconsciously, thanks, fixed that.

Comment: you can add the corresponding id to an attribute on div like rel or title or whatever, then just grab it when you need to use it

Comment: Here a very basic fiddle which you can use to do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/MaKNL/ . Click on the name below it will uncheck the checkbox above.

Comment: Okay, here is a fiddle for what I had. For some reason my add and remove buttons don't work in it.  http://jsfiddle.net/AzzyDude/uNMvs/1/

Comment: If the jQuery version is important, because some of these things seem to be working in the fiddle and some of them don't. My jQuery version is 1.4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I would go with this solution if it was me to implement it.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var $t = $(this), id = $t.attr('id'), $list = $('#list');
    if($t.is(':checked')){
        $list.append("<div class='member' data-id='" + id + "'></div>");
    }
})

function removeSlot(){
    var $t = $('.member').eq(-1), id = $t.attr('data-id');
    $('#' + id).attr('checked', false);
    $t.remove();
}
```

EDIT:

I think I get your meaning now. My idea is still using some attr to link the slot back to the checkbox. Please see if it works as you expect, http://jsfiddle.net/uNMvs/4/

```
var $list = $('#list');

$list.find('.member').attr('data-id', '-1');

$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   var $t = $(this), $lbl = $t.next(), 
       text = $lbl.html(), id = $t.attr('id');

    if($t.is(':checked')){
        $slot = $list.find('.member[data-id=-1]').eq(0);
        if($slot.size()) $slot.html(text).attr('data-id', id);
        else {
            alert('Please add another slot first');
            $t.attr('checked', false);            
        }
    } else {
        $list.find('.member[data-id=' + id + ']').attr('data-id', '-1').empty();
    }
});

$('#addSlot').click(function () {
    $list.append("<div data-id='-1' class='member'></div>");
})

$('#removeSlot').click(function () {
    var $slot = $list.find('.member').eq(-1);
    $('#' + $slot.attr('data-id')).attr('checked', false);
    $slot.remove();
})

​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this replacing my addSlot() function AND my removeSlot() function or is it just my removeSlot()? Sorry, this jQuery is a little over my head.

Comment: Yes, and I assume that you need to remove a slot when you uncheck a checkbox?

Comment: No, sorry, that can confuse things with the User due to the architecture of the rest of my document. Just need it so that if I remove a div that is populated, it takes the content of that div and uses it to uncheck the checkbox who's label corresponds to that content? That make sense?

Comment: I replaced my removeSlot() function with your edited code. I presume I keep my addSlot() as it is. I may have been wrong though, because the boxes don't seem to be unchecking

Comment: sorry but you may need to have the id assigned for the slot. as `$list.append("<div class='member' data-id='" + id + "'></div>");`

Comment: data-id is the key point in my solution to link slot back with the checkbox

Comment: Here's a Fiddle for what I had before your code. For some reason your code is adding a slot when I add a checkbox, so not sure I explained myself properly. http://jsfiddle.net/AzzyDude/uNMvs/1/

Comment: Also please note my add and remove buttons aren't working in the fiddle...I don't know if it has to do with my jQuery version? I'm using 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your fiddle, but some function not work:

i've change some part, like:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    var count = $('.member').length;
    var div_id = count + 1;
    $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + div_id + "' class='member'></div>");
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('.member:last').remove();
});
```

substitute function addSlot() and function removeSlot()

and

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Addslot" /><br />

<input type="button" value="RemoveSlot" id="remove" /><br />
```

this seem to work with jquery 1.4.4

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwz5/)

Comment: lol, for some reason those functions do work on my computer, just not in the fiddle. The real issue I'm having is regarding unchecking the person's name if you remove a slot with their name in it.

Comment: yes but i've not have too much time to test uncheck checkbox, i write this to work with a better fiddle ;-)

Comment: Hi, it's because the function addSlot() is in a closure in jsfiddle, so you can't see it from outside, as you chose 'onDomReady' as the location of the script. Thus, the onclick='addSlot()' would fail.